# Fill color from property via XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml

I am learning WPF and have this simple question.
How do I set fill color to property vi XAML?

```
<Rectangle Fill="{Binding Path=BackgroundColorf}" 
           Height="112" Margin="0,84,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
           Width="116"/>
```

```cs
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

         /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the BackgroundColor.  
        /// </summary>
   public SolidColorBrush BackgroundColorf
   {
       get;
       set;
   }

   public MainWindow()
   {
       this.InitializeComponent();
       BackgroundColorf =  new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red); 
   }
}
```

Comment: Have you set the DataContext?

Comment: no, i didn't... what should I set as datacontext?

Comment: Please read the [Data Binding Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx), this is basic stuff you should know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the datacontext like this

```
public MainWindow()
   {
       this.DataContext = this;      
       this.InitializeComponent();
       BackgroundColorf =  new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red); 
   }
```

This should work.But there is little more to be done for making your wpf app scalable like Notifications,Dependency properties etc.I recommend you go through the basics of wpf DataBinding architecture before continuing.Go through the link posted by H.B in the comments

Answer (score 1):

To get you going ...

Add a name to Rectangle

```
<Rectangle x:Name="MyRect" Fill="{Binding Path=BackgroundColorf}" Height="112" ...
```

then in the code

```
 InitializeComponent();
 MyRect.DataContext = this;
 BackgroundColorf = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
```

Not the best way of doing things - but at least you'll have a red rectangle :)

Answer (score 0):

if you add this your example will work

```
public MainWindow()
{
   this.InitializeComponent();
   this.DataContext =  this;
   BackgroundColorf =  new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red); 
}
```

but you should really in some wpf books or websites to get the basics.

a very good Book is "WPF 4 Unleashed" from Adam Nathan.